# Find the exhaustive set of values of 'a' such that log(x²+2ax)=log(8x-6a-3) has only one solution for x.

Tags: limits, functions, logarithms

Now I've tried to look up for the solution but haven't got any. One solution of a similar question makes the log functions on both sides disappear and simply makes the two brackets equal,
**x²+2ax=8x-6a-3**
and goes on to solve the equation. The values of a obtained via this method are 1 and 13. Now it can't be 13 because if a is 13 then x would be (-9). This can't be because if a equals 13 and x equals -9 then (8x-6a-3) becomes -153. Log of -153 is undefined. a=1 is a solution but I don't know how to solve for other values. The answer to this is open interval (-1/2, -3/22) and {1}. A detailed solution is much appreciated.

Comment: The logarithm is a one-to-one function: $\log u = \log v$ if and only if $u = v$. That is how they made the logarithm "disappear". However, this is not the entire story, because the logarithm is only defined on positive values. So for a given $a$, any $x$ that leaves $x^2 + 2ax = 8x-6a-3 \le 0$ is *not a solution* of the original equation even though it is a solution of the log-less version.

Comment: How did you arrive at $a = 1, 13$?

Comment: @Paul Sinclair.. making the log disappear we get x²+2ax=8x-6a-3. This is equal to x²+x(2a-8)+(6a+3)=0. Now if x has to have only one solution, we make the discriminant 0. This means (2a-8)² - 4(6a+3)=0. This gives 4a²+64-32a

Comment: @Paul Sinclair.. making the log disappear we get x²+2ax=8x-6a-3. This is equal to x²+x(2a-8)+(6a+3)=0. Now if x has to have only one solution, we make the discriminant 0. This means (2a-8)² - 4(6a+3)=0. This gives   4a²+64-32a-24a-12=0. 4a²-56a+52=0. Solving the quadratic, a²-14a+13=0 we get a²-13a-a+13=0. This gives the factors,  (a-1)(a-13). However, like you said, 13 is not in the domain.

Comment: (1) life is easier if you pull $4$ out of $(2a-8)^2 - 4(6a+3)=0$ to get $(a-4)^2 - (6a+3) = 0$ and proceed from there. But (2), It is not $x^2 + 2ax = 8x-6a-3$ that has only one solution Instead it is the logarithm equation. The condition you are looking for is that $x^2 + 2ax = 8x-6a-3$ exactly one solution $x$ *such that* $8x-6a -3 >0$.

Comment: @ Paul Sinclair yeah, but how to go about it? The answer is (-1/2, -3/22) as well as 1. How do I get that?

Comment: What is the problem with that? You know what the solutions (for $x$) of $x^2 + 2ax = 8x-6a-3$ are. Put the condition $8x > 6a -3$ on each of them, and figure out for which $a$ does exactly one of the solutions satisfy the condition.

Comment: @ Paul Sinclair I'm naive sir. Could you give me the detailed solution?

Comment: ? Why? You obviously know the quadratic formula. So you know for a given $a$ what the two solutions for $x$ are. I cannot believe you are incapable of plugging those two solutions into the inequality and solving it for $a$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair man I'm pretty exhausted. Tried the quadratic formula, the numbers are all over the place. If you can, then please provide with a bit detailed procedure. Maybe I'm making some stupid calculations errors or something. A detailed solution is really sought after man.

Comment: Actually, when I work through it (I hadn't actually done so before), what I come up with is there is one solution for $a$ in the closed interval $\left[\frac{728 - \sqrt{525232}}{264},1\right]$ (the lower limit of $\approx 0.0124$ is irrational), with two solutions below, and no solutions above.

Answer (score 1):

I think the method for this question is right here but slight mistake in this line
$29 -14a > 0$. It holds when $a<1$ but not when $a>13$, so if $\sqrt{8}a^2−14a+13 = 29−14a$, we must have $a<1$. Squaring both sides: $64a^2 − 896a + 832 = 196a^2 − 1624a + 841$.

Correct is 64a^2 − 896a + 832 = 196a^2 − 812a + 841$.

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need study the number of solutions of the system
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2+2ax = 8x-6a-3\\
8x-6a-3>0.
\end{cases}
$$
Solving the first equation for $a$ and replacing it in the inequality yields the condition on $x$
$$
-3<x<0 \lor x > \frac3{11}.\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
Now our aim becomes that of determining when the quadratic equation
$$x^2+2x(a-4)+6a+3=0\tag{2}\label{2}$$
has a solution satisfying \eqref{1}.

In order for the quadratic \eqref{2} to have *at least* one solution, we need $a\leq 1 \lor a\geq 13$.

However, for $a\geq 13$ the solutions are both less then $-3$ (can you say why?), thus condition \eqref{1} is not satisfied.

Let us consider now the case $a\leq 1$. Note that the larger solution of the quadratic is *decreasing* with $a$. On the other way around, the smaller one is an *increasing* function of $a$.

So while $a$ increases form $-\infty$ to $1$, the larger solution goes from $+\infty$ to $3$ (why?), whereas the smaller one goes from $-3$ (again why?) to $3$.

By easy direct check *the smaller solution is equal to* $0$ when $a=-\frac12$. Thus, from what we noted above, **for $a \leq -\frac12$ there are two solution to the original system**, one between $-3$ and $0$, and the other one greater than $3$.

Again by direct check, the smaller solution is equal to $\frac3{11}$ when $a=-\frac3{22}$. Hence for $-\frac12 < a < -\frac3{22}$ **the solutions of the system is one** (precisely, the larger solution of the quadratic, because the smaller one falls into the interval $\left[0,\frac3{11}\right]$).

For $-\frac{3}{22}\leq a <1$ again we have two solution to the original system (both greater than $\frac3{11}$).

Finally, we have one solution again for $a=-1$.

So your original equation has exactly one solution when
$$\boxed{-\frac12 < x < -\frac3{22} \lor a=1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the following method:

1. Firstly make a quadratic equation:
   We have log(x²+2ax) = log(8x-6a-3)
   Remove log from both sides, on rearranging,
   x²+(2a-8)x+6a+3=0
2. Now apply discriminant=0 for only 1 root of quadratic equation.
   (2a-8)²-4(1)(6a+3)=0
   On simplifying, a²-14a+13=0
   a=13 or a=1
   Putting a=13,our quadratic will become
   x²+18x+81=0 from here x=(-9) which makes 8x-6a-3, a negative quantity and hence log of it will be undefined.

Hence a=1 is a solution.

3. Think, if our quadratic i.e,
   **x²+(2a-8)x+6a+3=0**
   will have only one root then a=1 but if our quadratic has 2 roots and only one root satisfies the condition of the quantity in log is positive, then x has only one solution and it does not violate the question's guidelines.
   Consider any of the quantity in log
   (I am taking x²-2ax , you can also take
   8x-6a-3, and with the same method, answer will be same)
   Let the roots of this equation be **p and q**
   **Sum of roots = -(2a-8) = 8-2a
   Product of roots = 6a+3**
4. Now f(x) = x²-2ax
   f(p)×f(q)<0      [because any one of f(p) or f(q) is negative because any one of p or q is making negative and hence not satisfying the condition of log]

(p²-2ap)×(q²-2aq)<0
On expanding, **use p+q as sum and pq as product of roots of our quadratic**

On simplifying,you will get,
(6a+3)(22a+3)<0
Here is the answer of this inequality, **a** belongs to (-1/2, -3/22)
also we found that **a** = 1

*So the answer is
**a** belongs to (-1/2, -3/22)U{1}*

Answer (score -1):

The solutions $x$ of $x^2 + 2ax = 8x-6a-3$ are
$$x=4-a \pm \sqrt{a^2-14a + 13}$$

There are no solutions if the discriminant is negative, so we must have $a^2-14a + 13 = (a-1)(a-13) \ge 0$, which is true if and only if $a \le 1$ or $a \ge 13$.

As you've discovered, there is only one solution for this equation when $a =1$ or $a = 13$. But in addition to this equation being true, the logarithms of each side must exist, which means that $8x > 6a + 3$ must be true for $x$ to be a solution. For $a = 1, x = 3$, which meets the condition. But when $a = 13,x = -9$, which does not. So of those two, only $a=1$ provides a solution to the logarithmic equation.

But when the quadratic equation has two solutions, it can be case that one of those solutions satisfies $8x > 6a+3$, while the other does not. Then the logarithmic equation will have only one solution, as required. If for some value of $x, 8x > 6a+3$ holds, then it will also hold for all greater values of $x$. Thus it must be the greater of the two solutions for which $8x > 6a+3$, while it is false for the lower solution. Thus we are looking for values of $a$ such that

$$8\left[4-a -\sqrt{a^2-14a + 13}\right] \le 6a+3\quad\text{  and }\quad 8\left[4-a +\sqrt{a^2-14a + 13}\right] > 6a+3\\
8\sqrt{a^2-14a + 13} \ge 29-14a\quad\text{ and }\quad 8\sqrt{a^2-14a + 13} > 14a-29$$
As long as the square root is real, it is $\ge 0$, so either $29 - 14a > 0$ (whereby the RH inequality is automatically satisfied as $14a -29 < 0$) and $8\sqrt{a^2-14a + 13} = 29-14a$, or else $8\sqrt{a^2-14a + 13} > |14a-29|$.

$29 - 14a > 0$ holds when $a < 1$, but not when $a > 13$, so if $8\sqrt{a^2-14a + 13} = 29-14a$, we must have $a < 1$. Squaring both sides, $$64a^2 - 896a + 832 = 196a^2 - 1624a + 841\\132a^2 -728a + 9 = 0$$
of which, only the root
$$a= \frac{728 - \sqrt{525232}}{264} = \frac{182 - \sqrt{32827}}{66} \approx 0.0124$$
is less than $1$. When $a$ has this value, the lower of the two solutions $x$ of the quadratic is $\frac{6a+3}8$, which leaves $\log{8x-6a-3}$ undefined, while the other solution is greater, having well-defined logarithm.

The other condition for one root is $8\sqrt{a^2-14a + 13} > |14a-29|$, which again by squaring both sides leads to the condition $132a^2 -728a + 9 < 0$. This is true for $a$ approximately between $0.0124$ and $5.5$. But only the portion of that interval $\le 1$ lies in the range where $a^2 -14a + 13 \ge 0$. Thus there is only one solution $x$ when $a$ in the interval
$$\left[\frac{182 - \sqrt{32827}}{66}, 1\right]$$

Comment: thanks for the effort man. Appreciate it. This is exactly what I tried but this ain't the answer. The interval for a is [(-11/22, -3/22) U {1}].

Comment: While it is certainly possible that I've made a mistake and am just not seeing it, I find it more likely at this point that either that there is a mistake in the problem statement or that your source is wrong.

Comment: I'll surely reconfirm the answer I provided. However, I also plotted the graph of the functions with the constraints I provided for 'a' i.e., [(-1/2, -3/22) U {1}]. The graph seems good but I'll recheck.

Comment: If you take $a=\frac12$ you get $$\log(x^2+x) = \log(8x-6)$$ which I think has two distinct solutions, i.e. $x=1\lor x=6$.